# Google Sheets: how to bring drawing to top / bottom

Tags: google-sheets

I found workarounds for images by cutting an image and paste it again (so that would be the same to set on top).

And playing with right click, image options, image wrapping may help as well

But with drawings... I can't even cut or copy a drawing on Google Sheets. And right click do nothing.

So only 2 workarounds (which seems very uncomfortable in this case):

- Create the drawings in the desired order (first drawing would be on the button, last drawing would be on top)... But imagine we want to change the order...
- Create a single drawing (and order it all inside the single drawing). It may work for most of the cases... But in this particular case is even worse workaround.

So any way to do it properly?

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. _But with drawings... I can't even cut or copy a drawing on Google Sheets. And right click do nothing_ Have you tried: 1) select the drawing (note three dots in upper-right corner 2) click the dots and select "Edit", 3) in the drawing screen, select the drawing, 4) from the Drawings menu, selection "Actions", then "Cut/Copy/etc...

Comment: yeah @Tedinoz on the Edit or drawing screen is possible to change the order actually. It all would be the same image though. Thanks for the suggestion though! :)